# HTML updates not reflecting in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, caching

I am developing an AngularJS project. Each time I change the code, (html/css) and refresh the page, the changes are not reflecting. I already have cache: false in routes. By the way I am using dynamic routes using `ui-router` and `oclazyload`. To get the changes, I had to invoke developer tools in chrome (F12), with disable cache option and then do a refresh. Is there anything I am missing like versioning of HTMLs?

**Edit**

Here is my routes:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('layout', {
        url: '/:area',
        cache: false,
        templateUrl: function ($stateParams) {
            return 'app/areas/' + $stateParams.area + '/_layout/index.html'
        },
        resolve: {
            load: function ($ocLazyLoad, $stateParams) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    name: 'layout',
                    files: ['app/areas/' + $stateParams.area + '/_layout/controller.js']
                });
            }
        }
    })
    .state('layout.inner', {
        url: '/:action',
        cache: false,
        templateUrl: function ($stateParams) {
            return 'app/areas/' + $stateParams.area + '/' + $stateParams.action + '/index.html'
        },
        parent: 'layout',
        resolve: {
            load: function ($ocLazyLoad, $stateParams) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    name: 'layout.inner',
                    files: ['app/areas/' + $stateParams.area + '/' + $stateParams.action + '/controller.js',
                    ]
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What happens if you open the pages in a different browser? Do you see the changes?

Comment: if i already opened the page before, it isn't refreshing, otherwise it is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to get latest changes because your browser is caching old changes.

You said

*To get the changes, I had to invoke developer tools in chrome (F12), with disable cache option and then do a refresh*

*Disable cache* option will **only** be **active** when dev tools is **open**. As soon you close dev tools browser will start caching them again.

So, you either have to manually delete the cache <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or right click on refresh button and select *Empty Cache and Hard Reload* (Dev tools should be open).

For a simpler solution on *chrome*, you can use [Cache Killer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap?hl=en) extension. When it is enabled, each time page is refreshed it deletes all the cache.

Comment: What about the users? The applications gets some sort of enhancement now and then, which user may not aware or we cannot expect all users clear every time they visit the site.

Comment: For that you new need to set proper `cache` headers to let your `browser` know whether to `cache` pages or not

Comment: This will help..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers .